# Can Fuse Stance be applied to Wild Winds Stance and e.g. Gorilla Stance?

Tags: spells, feats, monk, pathfinder-2e, focus-pool

The [Wild Winds Stance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=489) focus spell grants a character a stance, which is entered by spending a focus point.

Does the [level 20 Fuse Stance feat](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=488) allow this stance to be used alongside another stance granted by a different monk feat - say, [Gorilla Stance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1733)? Would this be classes as "fundamentally different requirements", as one can only be entered by spending a focus point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## You can fuse those two, but...

Importantly, [Fuse Stance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=488) specifies that you "can't fuse stances with fundamentally incompatible requirements or restrictions (such as [Mountain Stance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=435) and [Crane Stance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=430), which both require using only one type of Strike)".

[Gorilla Stance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1733) also limits you to a specific type of Strike:

> While in this stance, the only Strikes you can make are gorilla slam unarmed attacks.

However, [Wild Winds Stance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=489) doesn't limit you to one type of Strike. There is also nothing incompatible about the focus point expenditure, since Gorilla Stance doesn't say anything like "you can't spend Focus Points" or "you can only spend Focus Points on spells with the Gorilla trait".

When you fuse the two stances, you'll only be able to make Gorilla Slam attacks. You will get the bonus to AC against ranged attacks from Wild Winds Stance though!

If you were to fuse something like [Tiger Stance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=436) with Wild Winds Stance, you could freely use either of the Strikes they grant.

Comment: I picked a bad example. The other stance I'm interested in is Whirling Blade Stance

Comment: @BenR. does this not answer the question for Whirling Blade Stance as well? Whirling Blade Stance (WBS) has zero requirements. It would be useless to fuse WBS with Gorilla Stance (GS), but if merged with Wild Wind Stance (WWS), you can still use either Strike, since neither WWS nor WBS specify a limitation to the types of Strikes you can make.

Comment: Yes, I meant I was interested in fusing whirling blade and wild winds.

Comment: @BenR. It may be best to include that in the question. Why not mention the specifics over a random example?